# IAP different product price for selected region in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

**I want to get the price of my subscriptions in the local currency for the region defined in the settings (Setting>Language/Region>Region)**

I have set up two subscriptions. Each subscription has different pricing for different regions. While retrieving products from the App Store, I am always getting the price in dollars.

If I check my country code using SKCloudService, I get 'in' (INDIA) but using SKPaymentQueue().storefront returns 'USA'.
The region of my device is set to 'India'.

**For checking region/country**

```
SKCloudServiceController().requestStorefrontCountryCode { (val, err) in
                if err == nil {
                    print("Country Code -  \(val)") //this return 'in'
                    
                    if let storeFront = SKPaymentQueue().storefront{ //this return 'USA'
                     
                    }else {
                
                    }     
                }
}
```

**For getting products from App Store**

```
public func requestProducts(_ completionHandler: @escaping ProductsRequestCompletionHandler) {
    productsRequest?.cancel()
    productsRequestCompletionHandler = completionHandler

    productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
    productsRequest!.delegate = self
    productsRequest!.start()
  }

 public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("Loaded list of products...")
    let products = response.products
    productsRequestCompletionHandler?(true, products)
    clearRequestAndHandler()

    for p in products {
      print("Found product: \(p.price.floatValue) \(p.price.priceLocale)") //this always show $ price and 'en_US@currency=USD' as currency
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is the phone appstore region set to ?  The store front returns "The current App Store storefront for the payment queue."

Comment: @TejaNandamuri current App Store region is 'India'

Comment: Did you add a localization of your subscriptions for India? Have you tried setting the device region to some other region where you have changed the price?

Comment: The pricing is determined by the purchasing App Store account's region, not the device region. . If you want to test Indian pricing, make sure you have set the sandbox users region to India.

Comment: @PaulSchröder yes tried with other regions. Same result.

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried with sandbox user and production (appstore). Same things happen. For some user it shows India pricing for some US pricing.